# What are the potential pitfalls of representing dates as nodes/vertices in Graph Database?

Tags: database-performance, graph-databases, titan

I am building a web application that involves many relational operations. For example, I have an 'event' node (representing an event, like a competition) during a particular `date` and I want to notify all the people about it who are in and around that place on that day.

In such a situation, it makes sense to have `date` as a separate node and linking it with both the `event` node and the `person` node. It is a good practice and is it better than storing the dates as properties (which I guess has some performance issue)? Also, can I try to represent all dates for all nodes as separate `day`, `month` and `year` nodes instead of defining them as properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stored the "date" as properties on an event, then you would have to use an index to find them.  Generally speaking indices are best when you have low selectivity so if you have tons of `event` vertices for a specific date it might not be so good to model the "date" as a property.   I suppose you would also need to consider use of an external indexing backend (e.g. elasticsearch) to help with range style queries given this approach.

If you have tons of events per date, then modelling the date as `day`, `month`, `year`, etc. vertices is a common pattern.  If you take this approach consider writing some [slick DSL](http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/07/25/developing-a-domain-specific-language-in-gremlin/) functions/steps to help easily navigate and work with that structure.